# Location of GO SDK

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I am a totally fresh user to GO programming language. I have downloaded the GO binary distribution go1.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz which is the latest for Ubuntu and started working with it. Currently, I can create simple GO programs and work using command line tools.

I have downloaded the IDEA IntelliJ 14.1.4 plugin for GO programming. When creating a project for this we need to set the SDK of GO. But so far I have been unable to find the SDK.

What is the location of the GO SDK? Is it available within the GO distribution or should we download it separately?

Comment: It _is_ the Go distribution. Just point it to the location where you extracted go1.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz to. Note however that the IntelliJ plugin was updated just a few days ago to handle 1.6, so you might have to update it for it to recognize the distribution.

Comment: okay for the moment I have tried by setting to the extracted distribution but they fail to recognize, I will upgrade the plugin and check.

Comment: It worked by upgrading the plugin, thanks for the help. If you drop in your answer here I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDEA plugin expects the location of the unpacked distribution for the "Go SDK".

It does check the version number and was just recently updated to support Go 1.6. Updating the plugin should fix the issue for you.